# Coverage stays at 100% when no tests are written for new methods

Tags: javascript, jestjs, code-coverage

I currently have the problem that newly added method calls are automatically tested in a function that has already been tested, thereby increasing the test coverage, although there are no explicit tests for these new methods.

Original code:

```
import { Controller } from "@hotwired/stimulus"

export default class extends Controller {
    static targets = [ "name", "output" ];

    declare readonly nameTarget: HTMLInputElement;
    declare readonly outputTarget: HTMLElement;

    greet() {
        this.outputTarget.innerHTML = this.name;
    }

    get name() {
        return this.nameTarget.value
    }
}
```

Test for this:

```
import HelloController from '../controllers/hello_controller'
import { Application } from '@hotwired/stimulus';

describe("HelloController", () => {
    describe("greet", () => {
        beforeEach(() => {
            document.body.innerHTML = `<div data-controller="hello">
                <input class="input" data-hello-target="name"  type="text">
                <p class="output" data-hello-target="output"></p>
                <button data-action="click->hello#greet">Greet</button>
            </div>`;

            const application = Application.start();
            application.register("hello", HelloController);
        });

        it("greets Person with given name", () => {
            const input = document.querySelector(".input") as HTMLInputElement;
            const output = document.querySelector(".output");
            const button = document.querySelector("button");

            expect(output.innerHTML).toEqual("");

            input.value = "foo";
            button.click();

            expect(output.innerHTML).toEqual("foo");
        });
    });
});
```

Now new methods were added to class (`_doSomething`):

```
import { Controller } from "@hotwired/stimulus"

export default class extends Controller {
    static targets = [ "name", "output" ];

    declare readonly nameTarget: HTMLInputElement;
    declare readonly outputTarget: HTMLElement;

    greet() {
        this.outputTarget.innerHTML = this.name;
        this._doSomething();
    }

    get name() {
        return this.nameTarget.value
    }

    _doSomething(): void {
        const wert = document.querySelector('body').getAttribute('data-ab-test');
    }
}
```

Tests are not changed.

If I run Jest coverage again. The newly added method is 100% covered. Although there are no tests.

In my opinion, the new method should be recognized as untested and the code coverage should decrease. But the coverage stays at 100% and the new method is shown as tested. What am I missing here?

Comment: It's **not** untested. It's invoked from a method that was already getting called in your test.

Comment: Yes, that's correct, but I didn't check in expect whether _doSomething does what it's supposed to. Now, if I just rely on test coverage, I have a 100% tested but unverified method.

Comment: Why would you just rely on test coverage - if you had new functionality that required a new method, why wouldn't you write a test _for that_ (ideally before implementing it). Coverage is just a heuristic, it doesn't tell you whether the tests are actually giving you the right information or whether the implementation actually works. Really it can only tell you what definitely _isn't_ tested (at that level, at least).

Comment: I would like to integrate the coverage into my CI pipeline. If the coverage falls below a certain value, the merge request should be rejected. However, if new methods do not affect the coverage without testing, my plan will not work.
I would like jest to have an option that automatically mocks all methods of a class and I only unmock the method under test. This ensures that no new method enters the code base without a test. Is there a solution for this in Jest?

Comment: That makes absolutely no sense, you shouldn't mock parts of the thing you're supposed to be testing. And "has X% test coverage" is neither necessary nor sufficient to determine if a merge request should be accepted, you have to _actually review it_. If people are submitting changes they haven't properly tested that's not a technical problem and can't be solved like one.

Comment: Of course you are right that code needs to be reviewed and tested. Nevertheless, I think that unit tests should be used to test the smallest possible unit of a class. Unit tests should support us in our work and code quality. I find it confusing if not wrong that untested methods are labeled as tested. I want to change this behavior. Does jest offer a solution for this?

Comment: They **are** executed during the tests. That's all coverage tells you, in _any_ tool - what _ran_. And unit tests cannot _"support us in our work and code quality"_ if they're too closely coupled to implementation, because then they actively _prevent_ you from refactoring to improve the quality. Test the class through the public interface (the naming convention `_doSomething` suggests that method isn't part of it) and use test doubles for _collaborators_.